# Handle Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 for validating user method

Tags: java, mysql

I have this method which validates a user trying to login to a web application I am hosting on Tomcat and If I enter a username which does not exist it gives me a `Index 0 out of bounds for length 0` instead of returning null and displaying the invalid login credentials page. How can I make sure it returns null if the username does not exist?

Validate user method:

```
 public User validateUser(Login login) {

// SQL statement
String sql = "select * from users where username='" + login.getUsername() + "'";
// Running query
List<User> users = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new UserMapper());
User user = users.get(0);
// Getting encrypted password
String encodedPassword = user.getPassword();
// Getting login password
String rawPassword = login.getPassword();
// Validating them
boolean isPasswordMatch = passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, encodedPassword);
if(isPasswordMatch){
    return user;
}
else { 
    return null;
}
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loginProcess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
@ModelAttribute("login") Login login) {
ModelAndView mav = null;
// Validating user
User user = userService.validateUser(login);
if (null != user) {
// Setting view
mav = new ModelAndView("loginProcess", "firstname", user.getFirstname());
// Creating session and saving user
HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(true);
httpSession.setAttribute("User", user);
}
// Returning invalid credentials
return mav = new ModelAndView("loginIncorrect");
}
```

Comment: you can have more than one user with same userName ? I think it should be unique, that way you will get only one record. Otherwise just check if users.isEmpty() or not. If it is not then get users.get(0) else its null. Something like -> users.isEmpty ? null : users.get(0);

Comment: "select * from users where username='" + login.getUsername() + "'"; this is just asking for SQL injection

Comment: Yes a username is unique.